# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string and pagination not working perfectly

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

**Finally my pagination worked.Still there are some problems.In every page its showing only one data and edit delete functionality not working.I tried changing almost everything.Any guidance will be great.**
**This is my controller**

```
function view($page=0){
        $config = array();
                $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "index.php/view_expenses/view";
                $config["total_rows"] = $this->emp_expenses_model->getTotalStudentCount();
                $config["per_page"] = 5;
                $this->pagination->initialize($config);
                $this->data["results"] = $this->emp_expenses_model->getStudent($config["per_page"], $page);
                $this->data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
                $this->data['title'] = 'Payroll System';
                $this->data['message'] = $this->session->flashdata('message');
                $this->load->view('view_expenses', $this->data);

    }
```

**This is the code in my model**

```
function getTotalStudentCount() {
            return $this->db->count_all("emp_expenses");
        }
      function getStudent($limit, $start) {
            $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
            $qry= $this->db->get("emp_expenses");
        return $qry->result();
         }
```

**and this is the view**

```
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0" id="tbl"  style="width:100%">
    <tr style="background-color:#045c97">
          <td class="heading">Expenses ID</td>
          <td class="heading">Employee ID</td>
          <td class="heading">Drop Down</td>
          <td class="heading">Mode OF Payment</td>
          <td class="heading">Amount</td>
          <td class="heading">Edit</td>
          <td class="heading">Delete</td>
    </tr>
     <?php
    foreach($results as $m)
      //var_dump($results);die('asd');
      ?> 
      <tr style="text-align:center;">
         <tr>
          <td><?php  echo $m->expenses_id ?></td>
          <td><?php  echo $m->id ?></td>
          <td><?php  echo $m->dropdown ?></td>
          <td><?php  echo $m->modeofpayment ?></td>
          <td><?php  echo $m->amount ?></td>
          <td><a href="<?php echo site_url('view_expenses/edit_expenses/'.$m) ?>"class="btn btn-primary btn-mini">Edit</a></td>
          <td>
          <?php 
          echo anchor('view_expenses/delete_expenses/'.$m, 'Delete', array('onClick' => "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"));
          ?>
          </td>
      </tr>
       <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links()?>
</table>
```

Comment: edit delete not working in place of edit button it showing  "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"....If i remove pagination edit delete working f9

Comment: Probably not related to the main problem but your `class=""` attribute on the edit button has no space between it and the closing quotes of the `href`. The main problem seems to be that your trying to echo `$m` on your edit buttons href attribute. `$m` is an object, not a string, you can access it's elements like you do further up the code, using something like `$m->id`. Same goes for the delete button.

Comment: u mean i have to add $m->['id'] after for each statement?

Comment: no... you have to use `$m->id`, because it is an object. If it was an array, you would use `$m['id']`.  I suggest reading some documentation on the basics of how arrays and objects work.

Comment: Hey jeemusu can u tell me also why its showing only one data per page

Comment: I would assume it's because your model only returns one set of data. Have you tried debugging the model? Before the `return` code, do something like `print_r($qry->result());die(); and see how many sets of data your getting. You may need to check your limit and offset variables are correct.

Comment: ya im restricting der,$result is showing only one data per page...how to change that

Comment: Debug, debug, debug... Debug all your variables related to retrieving the results, at different stages of your code. You can use echo,print_r,var_dump, etc to make sure they are all the values you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks bro for ur help.
In the model becoz of get expenses function im getting one value only,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, probably not related to the main problem but your class="" attribute on the edit button has no space between the start of the attribute and the closing quotes of the href.

The main problem seems to be that your trying to echo `$m`, on this line:

```
<?php echo site_url('view_expenses/edit_expenses/'.$m) ?>
```

`$m` is an object (containing multiple variables of information), your getting an error because your trying to treat it like a string.

Instead, you need to access one of these variables from within the object, just like you do further up in the code. I am guessing, you want the id, which would be `$m->id`.

Give this a go instead:

```
<?php echo site_url('view_expenses/edit_expenses/'.$m->id) ?>
```

The same goes for your delete button.

Comment: awsm man its so simple but yet complex :D help me with the pagination thing also if u can